# SQL Server Replication Agent Permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

> Error messages:
>   The schema script 'teste2_2.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
>
> The process could not read file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.VUZIQ_ENTP\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\ADSERVER$VUZIQ_ENTP_TESTE2_TESTE2\20130626155609\teste2_2.sch' due to OS error 3. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
>   Get help:

I have one sql from ip `199.168.***.***` working as Publication and another server `64.37.**.**`. working as Subscription. The local Subscriptions of `199.168.***.***` is working fine but the external access from `64.37.**.**` cant load file.

How can I add a login for `64.37.**.**` server to have read/write permission to `199.168.***.***` server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS error 3 means **path not found**.  You must specify a UNC network share such as \\computername\snapshot rather than a local path when using pull subscriptions and/or a remote Distributor.  This is covered in [Secure the Snapshot Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151151.aspx).  I have also covered this in a blog post found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlrepl/2011/11/30/the-process-could-not-read-file-due-to-os-error-3/) or [here](http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/the-process-could-not-read-file-due-to-os-error-3/).

Also, ensure your replication agent process account has read permissions on the snapshot share.  This can be done by right-clicking on the snapshot folder -> Properties, and adding the user on the Security tab with Read permissions.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: I dont know certainly why, but I just changed to Run all agents at the Distributor, and now all working fine, thanks!@Brandon Williams